# Meaning of different Stokes' coefficients in harmonic expansion of gravitational potential

Tags: geophysics, spherical-harmonics

I know that geophysical quantities, such as gravitational potential, can be written in terms of spherical harmonics:
$$W(r,\phi,\lambda;t) = \frac{G m_e}{r} + \frac{G m_e}{r} \sum_{l=2}^{N_{max}}\left( \frac{a_e}{r}\right)^l \sum_{m=0}^l \bar{P}_{lm}(\cos\phi)(\bar{C}_{lm}(t)\cos(m\lambda) + \bar{S}_{lm}(t)\cos(m\lambda))$$

where, in this case, W is the potential, $\phi$ is colatitude, $\lambda$ is longitude, l and m are, respectively, degree and order of the expansion, ${P}_{lm}$ the associated Legendre Polynomial and $C_{lm}$, $S_{lm}$ Stokes' coefficients.

My question is: once in the harmonic domain, how can I reconstruct the physical meaning of the various terms for varying degree and order? For example, in *Flattening of the Earth: further from hydrostaticity than previously estimated, (Chambat, Ricard, Valette)* it is said that $C_{20}$ is associated with the oblateness of the Earth, but nothing is said about the physical nature of the term $C_{40}$. I remember to have read somewhere that it is associated to hydrology, but I cannot find the source and I don't trust my memory.

Is there a way to find it out or is an experimental deduction based on the orders of magnitude of mass of the various Earth compartments (i.e. I know that the mass of equatorial bulge is bigger than hydrology terms, for example, the monsoons, and thus accounts in a term of lower degree and order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stokes coefficients are longitude dependent. c(4,0) would represent J(4,0); a zonal component of the associated legendre part of the potential due to gravity. That being said; the h2o being represented by an elliptical shape,, the next higher zonal harmonic shape would be j30. This is often called the pear shaped harmonic. J40 is the deviation from the the pear shape and of even smaller magnitude and symmetric about the north and south poles. As the value of n in Jn increases the magnitude of the jn decrease. j3 is a decrease in magnitude of 2.54x10^-6 from being symmetric, The actual Stokes coefficient C44 is of a sectional nature and longitude dependent. While Cn,m are known as the tesseral harmonics. An example of a zonal harmonic is the gradient of the potential due to gravity. Another is the electrical potential. See NASA Technical Memorandum X-53677 by J. von Puttkamer for "pictures".